# How to test if one java class extends another at runtime?

Tags: java, subclass, instanceof, class-hierarchy

How to I test if `a` is a subclass of `b`?

```
Class<?> a = A.class;
Class<?> b = B.class;
```

Answer (score 288, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
Super.class.isAssignableFrom(Sub.class)
```

Answer (score 96):

If you want to know whether or not a `Class` extends another, use [Class#isAssignableFrom(Class)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)). For your example, it would be:

```
if(B.class.isAssignableFrom(A.class)) { ... }
```

If you're interested in whether or not an instance is of a particular type, use `instanceof`:

```
A obj = new A();
if(obj instanceof B) { ... }
```

Note that these will return `true` if the class/instance is a member of the type hierarchy and are not restrictive to direct superclass/subclass relationships. For example:

```
// if A.class extends B.class, and B.class extends C.class
C.class.isAssignableFrom(A.class); // evaluates to true
// ...and...
new A() instanceof C; // evaluates to true
```

If you want to check for direct superclass/subclass relationships, [Tim has provided an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504870/how-to-test-if-one-java-class-extends-another-at-runtime/3504901#3504901) as well.

Comment: Actually, it B.class.isAssignableFrom(A.class), since he wants to know if A is a subclass of B.

Comment: Ah yes, I'll change that. Usually examples are the other way around (B extending A).

Comment: tricked ya ;-p  Many thanks for the detailed answer; I'm accepting meriton's though, as it is the clearest IMO.

Answer (score 51):

You want to know if `b` [is assignable from](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) `a`:

```
b.isAssignableFrom(a);
```

Additionally, if you want to know that `a` is a direct subclass of `b`:

```
a.getSuperclass().equals(b);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, and thanks for using `a` and `b` from the question