# Checking if a Class object is a subtype of another Class object in Java?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

Let's say I have two `Class` objects. Is there a way to check whether one class is a subtype of the other?

```
 public class Class1 { ... }

 public class Class2 extends Class1 { ... }

 public class Main {
   Class<?> clazz1 = Class1.class;
   Class<?> clazz2 = Class2.class;

   // If clazz2 is a subtype of clazz1, do something.
 }
```

Comment: Are you looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504870/how-to-test-if-one-java-class-extends-another-at-runtime

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if (clazz1.isAssignableFrom(clazz2)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

This checks if `clazz1` is the same, or a superclass of `clazz2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check like this:

```
if(Class1.class.isAssignableFrom(Class2.class)){

}
```