# Loading classes that extend another class from jars in directory

Tags: java, dynamic, reflection, loading

What I want to do is , let's say I have a folder , and that is a directory, and let's say I created a JAR that has a class in there that is extending "Apple". How would I check ALL JARS in that folder and check that they have class extending Apple, THEN add each and every one of those classes extending apple to my List?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205573/at-runtime-find-all-classes-in-a-java-application-that-extend-a-base-class) may help you. And see also google's [reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/)

Comment: @Wundwin: any alternatives to google reflections

Answer (score 1):

You have to use reflection API for this. First, get list of all classes loaded by class loader and then with the help of reflection API, you can check if a class extends Apple or not. Hope this helps

Comment: Can I have an example on how to to that? I've never use class loaders or tinkered with reflection.

Comment: Please refer to below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222638/get-all-of-the-classes-in-the-classpath and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504870/how-to-test-if-one-java-class-extends-another-at-runtime

Comment: How would it check for EVERY jar in there though?