# How to convert a string to a type that implements an interface?

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a string `com.bar.Baz`. I want to get `Class<T>`, where T is anything that extends an interface `com.bar.Foo` from the string.

Here is what I have tried but, it allows any class type, which is wrong.

**Updated:(Based on the comment)**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T extends Foo> Class<T> getClassOfTypeT(String clazz) {
        Class<T> ruleType = null;
        try {
            ruleType = (Class<T>) Class.forName(clazz);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error("Can't cast " + clazz, e);
        }
        return ruleType;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getClassOfTypeT("java.lang.String"));//Should not be allowed
    }
```

How to get `Class<T>` from a string?

Comment: First, let's use proper terminology; this method is not casting.

Comment: Second, bear in mind that generics are erased at runtime.  So you effectively just have `ruleType = (Class)Class.forName(clazz);`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504870/how-to-test-if-one-java-class-extends-another-at-runtime.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I strongly feel that this is not a duplicate. Help me understand how it is duplicate? I want to get an instance of Class from string right?

Comment: Yes, but you've solved that bit already. The bit you're currently dealing with is checking whether it extends from Foo.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thanks. Then, I think you can state the same as answer and remove duplicate. Because my question is different.

Comment: Your *problem* is identical.  Your *question* happens to also talk about something you're already solved ;)

Comment: Yes, @OliverCharlesworth is right. Your question finishes with "*How to get `Class<T>` from a string?*", whereas it should say "*How do I ensure `ruleType` extends `Foo`?*" In which case, the duplicate is correct.